Attempting to write a script to copy a file on desktop to another linux pc
rem I used:
cp /home/server1/filetocopy.ods to /server2/
rem second part is to copy to external usb drive
cp /home/server1/filetocopy.ods to /media/david/SEA_DISC1
rem results are:
target '/server1/ is not a directory
cannot stat '/home/server1/filetocopy.ods' no such file or directory
Attempted all variations of the path and file name with and without file name at destinations
I expected a copy of the file to be at the locations specified
I can access both locations in file manager and save and copy in that way
